# set /P if statement error (windows 8)

Tags: batch-file

can someone please tell me what is wrong with this line of code?

```
:Server
@echo off 
color 04
title Start Server
cls
echo Start your minecraft server? (y/n)
set /P %ServerChoice%=blah>nul

If %ServerChoice%==y start C:\Users\link1_000\Desktop\Bukkit_Craft\run.bat
pause>nul
goto :start
```

All it gives me is that `cd` was unexpected at this time, so then I run it with echo on to see if it changes directories, but it does't. Ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Not sure where the `cd` error is coming from since you don't actually *have* a `cd` in the code shown, but your `set` line should not have the percent signs:

```
set /P ServerChoice=blah>nul
```

With the percent signs, it actually *interprets* the environment variable, which isn't what you need.